# preg_match() replace a content in some text

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

can any one help me with that?

text:
this is a sample text with the number [RANDOM:100,200] that was made from a function

result:
this is a sample text with the number 153 that was made from a function

I want to search and replace this pattern from [RANDOM:100,200] to a number from 100-200

thanks you all..

```
$str = "this is my script [random:15;30] and I want to see if I found that.";
preg_match("/random:(.*)/", $str, $res);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: And so far you have attempted to achieve this goal how?

Comment: Assign a variable to it, then apply the search pattern to it.

Comment: I've added what I've tried..

Comment: my problem is how to find the [RANDOM:100,200] in the text.. I don't find the right pattern to that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
$str = "this is my script [random:15;30] and I want to see if I found that.";
preg_match("/\[random:(\d+);(\d+)\]/", $str, $res);

$random = rand($res[1], $res[2]);
$str = str_replace($res[0], $random, $str);

echo $str;
```